# Filter date to update pivot table daily

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I created a pivot table. Drag and place date into the filter field.

I am trying to automate the filtering of date to the previous working day so that the table will be updated daily.

Please help me thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help myself...

**Base Data Used:**

[image: Base Data Example]

**Pivot Table Layout:**

[image: Pivot Table]
[image: Pivot Table Setting]

Code Used:

```
' *** On Workbook Module ***
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call UpdatePivotTableDateToYesterday
End Sub

' *** In Module 1 ***
Option Explicit
Sub UpdatePivotTableDateToYesterday()
    Sheet5.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
    Sheet5.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = Format(Date - 1, "m/d/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to do for a specific date too?

Comment: Absolutely! Just replace `Format(Date - 1, "m/d/yyyy")` with `Format(Inputbox("Enter desired report date","Report Date",date -1), "m/d/yyyy")`